# WordUnderCursor not working as it should (word being detected when not on top of any words)

Tags: python, pyqt5

Why is a word being detected as being under the cursor here? The red arrow in the image starts where the cursor actually is. No matter where I place it, as long as it is inside the window, the program thinks a word is being selected. If the cursor is below the text, it defaults to the very last one. If the cursor is above, it defaults to the first one.

**IMAGE**:

[image: Sorry, I'm not allowed to embed images]

All of my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit, QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMouseEvent, QTextCursor


class Editor(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Editor, self).__init__()
        # make sure this widget is tracking the mouse position at all times
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, mouse_event: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        if self.underMouse():
            # create a QTextCursor at that position and select text
            text_cursor = self.cursorForPosition(mouse_event.pos())
            text_cursor.select(QTextCursor.WordUnderCursor)

            word_under_cursor = text_cursor.selectedText()
            print(word_under_cursor)

            # replace substring with placeholder so that repeat occurrences aren't highlighted as well
            selected_word_placeholder = self.replace_selected_text_with_placeholder(text_cursor)

            word_under_cursor = '<span style="background-color: #FFFF00;font-weight:bold;">' + word_under_cursor + '</span>'

            # replace the sentence with the new formatting
            self.setHtml(self.toPlainText().replace(selected_word_placeholder, word_under_cursor))

    def replace_in_html(self, old_string, new_string):
        old_html = self.toHtml()
        new_html = old_html.replace(old_string, new_string)
        self.setHtml(new_html)

    # use placeholder so that repeat occurrences of the word are not highlighted
    def replace_selected_text_with_placeholder(self, text_cursor):
        # remove the selected word to be replaced by the placeholder
        text_cursor.removeSelectedText()

        # create a placeholder with as many characters as the original word
        word_placeholder = ''
        for char in range(10):
            word_placeholder += '@'
        text_cursor.insertText(word_placeholder)

        return word_placeholder


def set_up(main_window):
    title_editor = Editor()
    title_editor.setText('Venda quente original xiaomi redmi airdots 2 tws fones de ouvido sem fio bluetooth fones controle ai gaming headset come')

    main_window.setCentralWidget(title_editor)
    main_window.show()


application = QApplication([])
window = QMainWindow()

set_up(window)

application.exec()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that `select()` always tries to select something, and even if the mouse is not actually *over* a text block, it will get the closest word.

The solution is to check if the mouse is *actually* inside the rectangle of the text block:

```
if self.underMouse():
    pos = mouse_event.pos()
    # create a QTextCursor at that position and select text
    text_cursor = self.cursorForPosition(pos)
    text_cursor.select(QTextCursor.WordUnderCursor)

    start = text_cursor.selectionStart()
    end = text_cursor.selectionEnd()
    length = end - start

    block = text_cursor.block()
    blockRect = self.document().documentLayout().blockBoundingRect(block)
    # translate by the offset caused by the scroll bar
    blockRect.translate(0, -self.verticalScrollBar().value())
    if not pos in blockRect:
        # clear the selection since the mouse is not over the block
        text_cursor.setPosition(text_cursor.position())
    elif length:
        # ensure that the mouse is actually over a word
        startFromBlock = start - block.position()
        textLine = block.layout().lineForTextPosition(startFromBlock)
        endFromBlock = startFromBlock + length
        x, _ = textLine.cursorToX(endFromBlock)
        if pos.x() > blockRect.x() + x:
            # mouse cursor is not over a word, clear the selection
            text_cursor.setPosition(text_cursor.position())
```

<sup>Please consider that, as suggested for your previous question, highlighting text using `setHtml` is *not* a good choice, as it always resets the contents of the editor; this is not only a problem for performance, but also for usability (even ignoring the scroll bar issue): `setHtml` always resets the undo stack, so the user cannot use undo operations anymore.</sup>

Comment: That's a nice solution. However still a word can be highlighted if the mouse is on a blank space to the right of the last word. I know, this is not a proper solution but just a work-around: you can add a white-space at the end of the text-edit content.

Comment: @angelogro you're welcome. And, no, adding a blank space is not a proper solution (and it would have made your solution working in any case), as it's possible to get the coordinates of the selection, I didn't implement it as I didn't believe it was required. See the update. Also consider that highlighting should *not* change the font width, or you will certainly get a "fuzzy" behavior whenever a word is close to the edge and it gets *pushed* to the next or previous line. The only proper changes are background/foreground colors and underline (even italic is not valid). See the update.